# UIPasteBoard "string" property returning nil despite "hasStrings" being true

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14, uipasteboard

I have the following code I use to grab text that a user has copied to the clipboard from outside the app so they can paste it in within the app:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

if ([pasteboard hasStrings])
{
    NSString *text = pasteboard.string;
}
```

This has always worked fine, until `iOS14` I notice I've been getting crashes because `pasteboard.string` is `nil` despite `hasStrings` being true.

I looked into the documentation and discovered that indeed, it's possible for `pasteboard.string` to be `nil`:

> The value stored in this property is an NSString object. The
> associated array of representation types is
> UIPasteboardTypeListString, which includes type kUTTypeUTF8PlainText.
> Setting this property replaces all current items in the pasteboard
> with the new item. If the first item has no value of the indicated
> type, nil is returned.

I take this mean to that some sort of string that is not `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` is in the clipboard and that's why `pasteboard.string` is `nil`, but is this the correct interpretation?

I'm just confused as to what exactly is happening here and am unsure what to tell my user if I reach the case where `pasteboard.string` is `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[UIPasteboard hasStrings] == YES` only means the items in pasteboard have type of `public.utf8-plain-text` or any other types that indicates it's a string.

But `-[UIPasteboard string]` can still return `nil` if object of class `NSString` cannot be constructed from any data provided by `itemProviders`.

Here is an example to reproduce the situation you are in:

First implement a test class that conforms to `NSItemProviderWriting`

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSString *const UTTypeUTF8PlainText = @"public.utf8-plain-text";

@interface TestObject : NSObject <NSItemProviderWriting>

@end

@implementation TestObject

- (NSData *)randomDataWithLength:(NSUInteger)length {
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, data.mutableBytes);
    return data;
}

#pragma mark - NSItemProviderWriting

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider {
    return @[UTTypeUTF8PlainText];
}

- (nullable NSProgress *)loadDataWithTypeIdentifier:(nonnull NSString *)typeIdentifier forItemProviderCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSData * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    // random data that an utf8 string may not be constructed from
    NSData *randomData = [self randomDataWithLength:1];
    completionHandler(randomData, nil);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Then put the test object into pastboard

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    TestObject *item = [TestObject new];
    [pasteboard setObjects:@[item]];
    
    if ([pasteboard hasStrings]) {
        // text may be nil
        NSString *text = pasteboard.string;
    }
}
```